# How to create an inline formset with manytomany relation in Django

Tags: django, inline, inline-formset

I want to create an inline formset between **Preorder** model and **Product** model. The scenario is that the user will be able to select one or more than one products when he decides to create a preorder. On the other hand a product might be found in one or more than one preorders. With that in mind i created a manytomany relationship.

models.py

```
class Preorder(models.Model):

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,verbose_name=u'Client')
    invoice_date = models.DateField("Invoice date",null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.date.today)
    preorder_has_products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('preorder_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField("Name",max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField("Price", max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, default="")
    eopyy = models.CharField("Code eoppy",max_length=10, blank=True, default="")
    fpa = models.ForeignKey(FPA, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Fpa Scale')
```

forms.py

```
class PreorderForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Preorder
        exclude = ('client','preorder_has_products',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PreorderForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['invoice_date'].widget = MyDateInput(attrs={'class':'date'})

class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    #name = ModelChoiceField(required=True,queryset=Product.objects.all(),widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='name-autocomplete'))
    class Meta:
        model=Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].label="Name"
        self.fields['price'].label="Price"
```

and finally the inline formset:

```
PreorderProductFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Preorder, Product,
                                             form=ProductForm, extra=1)
```

After run I face up the issue:**ValueError at /
'intranet.Product' has no ForeignKey to 'intranet.Preorder'**

Why this happening since I created a manytomany relation?

One solution is to create a foreign key relationship between Preorder and Product model inside Product model..but I do not want to do that since product model is used in other areas of my project and do not want to mess it up.

Any suggestions?